# PHP output to semicolon

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
    // Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT usuarios.id, usuarios.cedula, usuarios.estado, usuarios.nombre, facturas.idcliente, facturas.total\n"
    . "FROM usuarios\n"
    . "LEFT JOIN facturas ON usuarios.id=facturas.idcliente";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "" . $row["id"]. " " . $row["nombre"]. " " . $row["estado"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

and the results are shown in this way:

> 000002 Luis Anel Jimenez ACTIVO
>   000008 Alexis Gaitan ACTIVO
>   000010 LUIS JIMENEZ ACTIVO

I need to show results like this:

> 000002;Luis Anel Jimenez;IDENTIFICADOR_EPAGO;88191;ESTADO: ACTIVO

I tried this code:

```
   $data = [];
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = implode(";", [$row["id"],$row["saldo"],$row["nombre"],"IDENTIFICADOR_EPAGO",$row["cedula"],"ESTADO: " . $row["estado"],"\r\n" ]);
    }
    if(count($data)) {
        file_put_contents("epago.txt", $data);
    }
                          } else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

but I'm getting:

> 000002;;Luis Anel Jimenez;IDENTIFICADOR_EPAGO;88191;ESTADO: ACTIVO;

Is there anyway to remove that extra semicolon `;` after first variable and in the last variable `ACTIVO;`?

Comment: *"and the results are shown in this way"* - And "what" way *should* they be? You didn't say what the problem was.

Comment: *"and then save it to a .TXT file"* - Where's that bit to save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and maybe little bit dirty ;-)

```
$data = [];
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        // Dont add the \r\n as array entry, because it will be removed
        // the string is concated and you open it with a texteditor
        // Implode did concat all array values with the sign that you
        // provide with the first parameter. 
        // This will end up in field1;field2;field3;field4;\r\n and so
        // on, this will end up in a trailing ; on your lines
        $data[] = implode(";", [ $row["id"],$row["nombre"],$row["estado"] ]);
    }
    if(count($data)) {
        // Its urgent, that you implode here all "lines" from the array
        // This will prevent, that lines will end with ; because
        // the \r\n will be removed, if you read them with a texteditor
        file_put_contens('path/to/your/file.txt', implode("\r\n", $data));
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: Im getting this 000002;;Luis Anel Jimenez;IDENT first variable ;; double semicolon

Comment: Then you have to proof, that you have the same line like me. If its the same, then check $row["id"] and $row["nombre"] (values) that there is no ; in it.

Because this little snippet will not produce ;;, its impossible when none of the 3 values from the line ...implode()... have a ; in it.

Comment: you right i checked the nombre value now im getting correct data 000002;94.16;Luis Anel Jimenez;IDENTIFICADOR_EPAGO;88191;ESTADO: ACTIVO; but, theres any chance to remove that last ; ?

Comment: Thats because you didnt copy my code right ...

You did add the new line character (\r\n) into the data array. So this will be the last entry in your array. Implode did concat all array values into a string, separated by the sign, that you give with the first parameter.

So now, it would do the following

field1;field2;field3;field4;\r\n

But the \r\n is a "protected" word, it will disappear in all modern text editor, so it ends up with 

field1;field2;field3;field4;

Hope you can understand, whats wrong with your code. I did edit my main post.